# Untrusted SSL Certificates in Firefox Using WebDriver and C#

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

UPDATE: i upgrade to Selenium 2.37 but still having the same problem!!

LATEST EDIT: still does not work after defining the pref (see below)

```
              //some more prefs:
                profile.SetPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
                profile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", _url);                     
                profile.SetPreference("webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer", true); 
                profile.SetPreference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs", true);
                profile.SetPreference("trustAllSSLCertificates", true);
```

I'm using FF 25.0.1
Webdriver version: 2.31

I never had this problem before but just started when i start running my automated test cases so what is happening is that i am getting SSL certification error and even though i have accepted and add as an exception but i still getting the error and hence my test case is failing...

here is what i have added when i'm building ff webdriver...

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
profile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", _url);                     
profile.SetPreference("webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer", false);                    
drv = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

[screen shot.](http://chrisedwards.dreamhosters.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/UntrustedSSLCert-300x167.gif)

Comment: As I understood you have to accept untrusted ssl certificate in selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Can you set this preference as true and try -- webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs

Comment: The other work around is to manually save the certificate and save it as a Firefox profile and use it in the driver initialization. Refer these examples on how to set Firefox profile  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you are not running selenium with -trustAllSSLCertificates -switch?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this too, but with Java API. I just discovered this issue on Selenium 2.35, hoping a resolution upgrading in 2.37...
The problem is there with both firefox 24.0.1 and 25.0.
It works with ChromeDriver

For now, I found only one website where the problem occurred (https://twitter.com)
IS the website your testing is public ? I would appreciate to reproduce on another place.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the way @Akabar wrote above in the comment and I can share more detail s about how I fix this issue:
You can check here for your reference: [Selenium Webdriver: Surpressing untrusted connection message in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158473/selenium-webdriver-surpressing-untrusted-connection-message-in-firefox/39585000#39585000)

The steps are:

Step 1 - Open your FF manually and accept the self-signed certificate manually (I mean accept "sec_error_unknown_issuer" security exception)

Step 2 - Locate your FF's profile directory and copy the path of the your profile directory, ex(MAC env): "/Users/UserABC/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/vndms5adearwtry.default"

Step 3 - In your selenium code(java version), use the following way to init the FirefoxDriver:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("/Users/UserABC/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/vndms5adearwtry.default"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Hope it helps.